# Missing 'PactFragment' in package au.com.dius.pact.model

Tags: pact, pact-java

I am new to Pact.

I downloaded the code from Github, "pact-jvm" project.
I created a new project in *IntelliJ* from "existing source" with Gradle setting.
It imported all the packages fine.

However, when I tried running some of the tests in it, I got a

> cannot find symbol

error as the following,

> Error:(5, 30) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class PactFragment
>     location: package au.com.dius.pact.model

I looked at my package 'package au.com.dius.pact.model' and I found that "PactFragment" is missing from this package.

In addition to that, the following classes are also missing in this package.

```
import au.com.dius.pact.matchers.MatchingConfig
import au.com.dius.pact.model.BodyMismatch
import au.com.dius.pact.model.BodyTypeMismatch
import au.com.dius.pact.model.DiffConfig
import au.com.dius.pact.model.HeaderMismatch
import au.com.dius.pact.model.ResponseMatching$
import au.com.dius.pact.model.ResponsePartMismatch
import au.com.dius.pact.model.StatusMismatch
```

However, I did a "git pull" on all the source code from Github for the "pact-jvm" project. When I do "git pull", it shows that everything is "Already up-to-date."

Any pointers what I might be missing?
Why am I missing so many classes in this package, 'package au.com.dius.pact.model'?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: I know this is being answered via our email list.  When you do in fact get your solution, please answer your own question and accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After re-importing the project from scratch as a Gradle project and install the scala plugin. The problem is solved.

Comment: I tried to close it. But I was only given a closes option to close as a duplicate. When I was asked which issue is duplicated, I don't know the answer and cancel it. But after that, when I to to flag, I am only given one option, "in need of moderator intervention". What the proper next step now? Should I delete my post?